# Attach files to record in Netsuite

Tags: file, netsuite, zoho

I am transferring attachments from Zoho to Netsuite. But facing problems while attaching it to opportunity or any other object. I have already uploaded the file to the file cabinet in netsuite and tried to bind it with the records notes. But that doesn't work. It only adds the note to the record but no sign of any file in the file option.

Thank you.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExE2J.png)

Answer (score 2):

You would use the `record.attach` function. You would need the internal id of the file and of the transaction. In SS1 (using `nlapiAttachRecord`) it was important to list the file arguments first. The SS2 syntax makes that clearer:

```js
record.attach({
    record:{
        type:'file',
        id:fileid
    },
    to:{
        type:'transaction', 
        id:transactionid
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. It worked but will this work on the mass level. I have around 11k attachments that need to be attached with the opportunity.

Comment: @HarjinderSingh no idea if there is a limit. If you succeed the opportunity page may be vey slow to load. And how would you see someone making use of this? Just zip the 11k files and let whoever might need them download and navigate them. Or save them on S3 and provide a link or an external file inspector

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
* @NApiVersion 2.1
* @NScriptType MapReduceScript
* @NModuleScope SameAccount
*/

/**
* In this I am using Map Reduce script to process & attach multiple files from 
* FileCabinet of NetSuite. So that it never goes out of governance.
/
define(['N/record','N/query'],
(record,query) => {
  const getInputData = (getInputDataContext) => {

    try
    {
      /**
      * Query for getting transaction ID & other header detail of record.
      */
      let transQuery = "SELECT custrecord_rf_tid as tid, custrecord_rf_fid as fid, id FROM customrecord_rflink where custrecord_rf_comp <> 'T' and custrecord_rf_type = 11";
      let transQueryResult = runSuiteQuery(transQuery);

      if(transQueryResult.length > 0){
        log.debug("Count of record left to process--->", transQueryResult.length);
        return transQueryResult;
      }else{ //Incase where no transaction was left to transform.
        log.debug({title: "No Remaining Transaction!"});
        return 1;
      }
    }
    catch (e)
    {
      log.error({title: "Error inside getinput data.", details: [e.message,e.stack]});
    }
  }

 
  const map = (mapContext) => {
    try{
      let mapData = JSON.parse(mapContext.value);
      log.debug({title: "mapData after parse", details: mapData});

      let staginRecId = Number(mapData.id);
      let fileId = Number(mapData.fid);
      let billId = Number(mapData.tid);

      let outputVal = attachfile('file',fileId, 'inventoryadjustment', billId);

      let staginRec;
      if(outputVal === true){
        staginRec = record.submitFields({
          type: 'customrecord_rflink',
          id: staginRecId,
          values: {
            'custrecord_rf_comp': true
          }
        });
        log.debug("record saved with id-->", staginRecId);
      }else{
        log.debug("record saving failed with id-->", staginRecId);
      }


    }
    catch(e){
      log.error({title: "Error in Map", details: [e.message,e.stack]});
    }
  }   

  const reduce = (reduceContext) => {

  }

  const summarize = (summarizeContext) => {
    log.debug('Summarize completed');
  }

  function runSuiteQuery(queryString) {
    log.debug("Query", queryString);
    let resultSet = query.runSuiteQL({
      query: queryString
    });
    log.debug("Query wise Data", resultSet.asMappedResults());
    if(resultSet && resultSet.results && resultSet.results.length > 0) {
      return resultSet.asMappedResults();
    } else {
      return [];
    }
  }
  function attachfile(recType, recId, recTypeTo, recIdTo) {
    record.attach({
      record: {
        type: recType,
        id: recId
      },
      to: {
        type: recTypeTo,
        id: recIdTo
      }
    });

    return true;
  }
  return {getInputData,map,reduce,summarize};
});
```